# How to add data to array and apply increase Qty for that?

Tags: ruby

hi i have an array that dimension after mining push to that how can i increase Qty after each pushing for similar dimension?
suppose to we have this array:
[x,y,Qty]

```
b=[]
b.push[100,50,1]
b.push[20,30,1]
b.push[100,50,1]
b.push[10,60,1]
```

how can i have this result: `b = [ [100,50,2],[20,30,1],[10,60,1] ]`

Comment: are you sure you want to do that with arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we are given the following (which differs slightly from the example).

```
b = [[100, 50, 1], [20, 30, 2], [100, 50, 1], [10, 60, 1]]
```

Let's begin with a relatively inefficient solution and then see how it can be improved.

**Staightforward but relatively inefficient solution**

We first compute the following array.

```
arr = b.map { |x,y,z| [x, y] }
  #=> [[100, 50], [20, 30], [100, 50], [10, 60]]
```

Before continuing suppose `b` were to change in future such that each element contain four, rather than three, values, such as `[100, 50, 20, 2]`. We could change the calculation of `arr` to `arr = b.map { |w,x,y,z| [w, x, y] }`, but a better solution is to use the [splat operator](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/ruby-splat-array-manipulation-destructuring/), `*`, to perform [Array#decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition). By using the splat operator we need not change this code if the size of the elements of `b` changes.

```
arr = b.map { |*a,z| a }
  #=> [[100, 50], [20, 30], [100, 50], [10, 60]]
```

For each element (array) `e` of `b`, the array `a` will contain all but the last element of `e` and `z` will contain the last element of `e`, regardless of the size of `e`.

Next we use the method [Array#uniq](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) to obtain the unique elements of `arr`.

```
arr_uniq = arr.uniq
  #=> [[100, 50], [20, 30], [10, 60]]
```

We may then compute the desired array as follows.

```
arr_uniq.map do |a|
  tot = 0
  b.each { |*c,z| tot += z if a == c }
  [*a, tot]
end
  #=> [[100, 50, 2], [20, 30, 2], [10, 60, 1]]
```

Recall that `tot += z` is effectively the same as `tot = tot + z`.

This approach is relatively inefficient because the array `b` is traversed completely for each element of `arr_uniq`. We should be able to make only a single pass through `b`.

**Improving efficiency**

We step through each element of `b` to construct a hash.

```
h = {}
b.each do |*a,z|
  if h.key?(a)
    h[a] += z
  else
    h[a] = z
  end
end
h #=> {[100, 50]=>2, [20, 30]=>2, [10, 60]=>1}
```

We now need only convert `h` to the desired array (though it may be more useful to stop here and use the hash for subsequent calculations).

```
h.map { |k,v| [*k, v] }
  #=> [[100, 50, 2], [20, 30, 2], [10, 60, 1]]
```

We now consider how to make this calculation more Ruby-like.

**Wrapping up**

To improve upon the construction of `h` above we make use of two methods: the form of class method [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument called the *default value*; and [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object).

```
b.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(*a,z),h| h[a] += z }
 .map { |k,v| [*k, v] }
 #=> [[100, 50, 2], [20, 30, 2], [10, 60, 1]]
```

This first step is to compute a hash:

```
b.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(*a,z),h| h[a] += z }
  #=> {[100, 50]=>2, [20, 30]=>2, [10, 60]=>1}
```

You may wish to review the link to *array decomposition* that I gave earler to see how the block variables `a`, `z` and `h` in `|(*a,z),h|` are assigned values.

If a hash is defined

```
h = Hash.new(0)
```

`h[k]` returns the default value, here zero, if `h` does not contain a key `k`.

Initially,

```
h[[100, 50]] += 1
```

expands to

```
h[[100, 50]] = h[[100, 50]] + 1
```

Since `h` has no keys at this time--specifically no key `[100, 50]`--`h[[100, 50]]` on the right returns the default value, so the expression becomes

```
h[[100, 50]] = 0 + 1
h #=> { [100, 50] => 1 }
```

Later, when the same key `[100, 50]` is encountered (when `h #=> { [100, 50] => 1, [20, 30] => 2 }`), the expresson becomes

```
h[[100, 50]] = 1 + 1
h #=> { [100, 50] => 2, [20, 30] => 2 }
```

This time, `h` has a key `[100, 50]`, so `h[[100, 50]]` on the right returns its value, which equals `1` (and the default value is not used).

**Alternative method: use [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)**

We could alternatively compute the desired array as follows.

```
b.group_by { |*a,z| a }
 .map { |k,v| [*k, v.sum(&:last)] }
 #=> [[100, 50, 2], [20, 30, 2], [10, 60, 1]]
```

The first step is to compute a hash:

```
b.group_by { |*a,z| a }
  #=> {[100, 50]=>[[100, 50, 1], [100, 50, 1]],
       [20, 30]=>[[20, 30, 2]], [10, 60]=>[[10, 60, 1]]}
```

When compared to the method above that employs `Hash::new`, this calculation has the minor disadvantage that the memory requirements for the values in the intermediate are somewhat greater.

Comment: tank you Cary its work true . but is this possible we use group_by method? or i wrong?

Comment: I modified my answer to include the option of using `Enumerable#group_by`.

Comment: tank you mr Cary Swoveland . really helpful .